# Making a word scrambler in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordScrambler 
{
    public String prefix, inner, postfix, newword;


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String words = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(words);
    }


public void Scrambler()

}

String [] words = words.split(" ");

}
```

}

I'm not really understanding how to get my variable "words" into my scramble method so i can split each word that i put into seperate strings, am i just declaring a new array words when i do this? How do i grab that variable from above. Also, my system.out.println is just checking to see if my scanner worked. Or am i doing it right and is it actually splitting the words?

Comment: There's not a matching number of opened and closed brackets in your code.  It's difficult to see which logic you expect to work, where, when the code syntax is incorrect.  Is "Scrambler" supposed to be a class that scrambles "words" input? If so, add the brackets to it that help outline this.

Comment: Sorry about that, i fixed it and yes scrambler is supposed to be a class

Comment: See what RayStojonic and gjman2 suggested, I think either will get you where you need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordScrambler {

    public String prefix, inner, postfix, newword;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String words = sc.nextLine();
        WordScrambler wordScrambler = new WordScrambler();
        wordScrambler.scrambler(words);

    }

    public void scrambler(String words) {

        String[] word = words.trim().split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(word[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you simply want to pass a variable from one method to another.

sidenote: in Java, method names begin with a lowercase letter and are usually verbs: scramble not Scrambler

In:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    String words = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(words);
}
```

You've gotten the input, but still don't have anywhere to send it because you haven't created an instance of WordScrambler yet.

So, let's make one of those:

```
WordScrambler wordScrambler = new WordScrambler();
```

Okay, now you have access to the scramble method, so

```
wordScrambler.scramble( words )
```

Will get things moving

Now, you'll need to do something with that String in scramble (after you fix the method declaration to accept a String parameter), like split it, jumble the words and output the result, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable to the method as a parameter. If you make the method `static`, you can call it simply from your `main()`.

Also, name your input as (obviously) `input`, because that's what it is.

Here's how I would do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(scramble(input));
}

public static String scramble(String input) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input.trim().split("\\s+")));
    Collections.shuffle(words);
    return words.toString().replaceAll("[^\\w ]", "");
}
```